# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 300 into shape (100,100,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reshape

I'm struggeling in reshaping my image. Which is of dimension (100,100,3). The total array for all images makes up (3267, 100, 3)

```
def get_batch(batch_size,s="train"):
    """Create batch of n pairs, half same class, half different class"""
    if s == 'train':
        X = Xtrain
        X= X.reshape(-1,100,100,3)
        #X= X.reshape(-1,20,105,105)
        categories = train_classes
    else:
        X = Xval
        X= X.reshape(-1,100,100,3)
        categories = val_classes
    n_classes, n_examples, w, h, chan = X.shape
    print(n_classes)
    print(type(n_classes))
    print(n_classes.shape)
    # randomly sample several classes to use in the batch
    categories = rng.choice(n_classes,size=(batch_size,),replace=False)
    
    # initialize 2 empty arrays for the input image batch
    pairs=[np.zeros((batch_size, h, w,1)) for i in range(2)]
    
    # initialize vector for the targets
    targets=np.zeros((batch_size,))
    
    # make one half of it '1's, so 2nd half of batch has same class
    targets[batch_size//2:] = 1
    for i in range(batch_size):
        category = categories[i]
        idx_1 = rng.randint(0, n_examples)
        pairs[0][i,:,:,:] = X[category, idx_1].reshape(w, h, chan)
        idx_2 = rng.randint(0, n_examples)
        
        # pick images of same class for 1st half, different for 2nd
        if i >= batch_size // 2:
            category_2 = category  
        else: 
            # add a random number to the category modulo n classes to ensure 2nd image has a different category
            category_2 = (category + rng.randint(1,n_classes)) % n_classes
        
        pairs[1][i,:,:,:] = X[category_2,idx_2].reshape(w, h,1)
    
    return pairs, targets
```

However when trying to reshape the array `pairs[0][i,:,:,:] = X[category, idx_1].reshape(w, h, chan)` I always obtain the error that an array size of 300 is not reshapable into (100,100,3). I honestly don't see the problem why it should be...
Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want array of 300 into 100,100,3. it cannot be because `(100*100*3)=30000` and `30000 not equal to 300` you can only reshape if output shape has same number of values as input.

i suggest you should do `(10,10,3)` instead because `(10*10*3)=300`